# More work getting assigned, lot of criticism and bully - signifies what

Tags: work-environment, politics, bullying

I am working as a lead in software company. I have been given 2-3 projects to manage simultaneously. I have been spending more than 12 hours in a day. In short lot of work one after the another.

But what I am not getting is if I am that good then why there is criticism like `"you missed this"`, `"you missed that"`, `"we don't expect this from you"`, `"you are a lead someday you will be manager, think like that"`, `"this will not be good for you"`, `"you will be replaced if you do this again"`. Such comments making me uncomfortable and I see that people those are getting less work, better salary but living more peaceful life. They simply need to say "no" or use any escapism funda like "fever", "guests at home" etc.

Also I am worried that on "D" day i.e. appraisal meeting, they will pick above things and rate me poor. But now they say `"you have potential"`, `"you have proven"` so we are giving more work to you.

Or may be I am thinking wrong, what all this is signaling? Should I also behave like others.

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple. You are working 12 hours a day, and most people would realise that you can't do useful work for 12 hours day in the long term. It's inevitable that your work will suffer. Your brain isn't functioning anymore if you work and work and work - quite apart from the fact that it destroys your life.

Depending on the attitude of your management, looking for a job elsewhere might be a good idea. Things can't go on as they do at your company. If your management think they can, leaving may be inevitable.

You already realised that some people just say "no". That's what you need to do as well. It seems your managers try to manage by fear and it "works" with people like you (but only as far as they make you 12 hours a day, not as far as getting a good job done) and it doesn't "work" for people who say "no".

If you are leading two projects, and working 12 hours a day, then you say "no" if anyone wants to give you more work. You also focus on spending 8 hours a day leading the teams for the two projects and don't do any additional work after that. Your results will improve. You will produce 8 hours of good work instead of 12 hours of rubbish work.

And you *know* that this strategy of saying "no" works well for others, and your strategy isn't working for you. By changing your strategy you will do a better job and at the same time lead a better life. And your management will think better of you. Working overtime doesn't make you go up their estimation one bit.